# Blocking SSL_read() causes a crash when partner closes connection, using threading

Tags: multithreading, sockets, ssl, openssl

I am writing a program using OpenSSL for connections. It all works fine using blocking sockets and threads except for one single option:

My thread 1 calls SSL_read() and waits for it to receive anything - but if the connections is closed by the partner the SSL_read() causes a crash.

Is there a way to still do it with blocking and threads or do I have to use SSL_pending and non blocking sockets? (I just heard of it don't know how to use it, so I wanted to ask, whether I will have to implement it this way, first..)

Thanks in advance,
-fodinabor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are really doing. Blocking SSL_read together with threads is not a problem by itself. Maybe you should read the relevant part about threads in the [OpenSSL FAQ](https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG1). Especially the following part might be relevant for you:

> ... an SSL connection may not concurrently be used by multiple threads

Comment: Thank you - I had a look and added a selfmade Mutex and error checks I did not find before!